# unique.data.table do not handle keys properly

Tags: r, key, unique, data.table

I have this `data.table`, called `A`:

```
    kom eje               gad num     enc
 1: 101   1 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 2: 101   2 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 3: 101   3 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 4: 101   4 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 5: 101   5 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 6: 101   6 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 7: 101   7 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 8: 101   8 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 9: 101   9 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
10: 101  10 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
11: 101  11 A.C. Meyers Vænge  10 unkwown
12: 101  12 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11 unkwown
13: 101  13 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11   UTF-8
14: 101  14 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
15: 101  15 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
16: 101  16 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
17: 101  17 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
18: 101  18 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
19: 101  19 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
20: 101  20 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
```

`A` is keyed by `kom`, `gad` and `num`.

```
setkey(A,kom,gad,num)
```

However `unique(A)` returns wrongly (and without warning):

```
    kom eje               gad num     enc
 1: 101   1 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 2: 101   2 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 3: 101   4 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 4: 101   5 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 5: 101   6 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 6: 101   7 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 7: 101   9 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1   UTF-8
 8: 101  10 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
 9: 101  11 A.C. Meyers Vænge  10 unkwown
10: 101  12 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11 unkwown
11: 101  13 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11   UTF-8
12: 101  14 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
13: 101  15 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
14: 101  17 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
15: 101  19 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A   UTF-8
```

Since `A` i keyed, I would expect `unique` to focus on only these columns, as specified in `unique.data.table` documentation. Clearly lines 1 and 2, and 4 and 5, are errors. This appear to give the correct answer:

```
B <- A[.(101,'A.C. Meyers Vænge')] # warning about encoding
unique(B)
   kom               gad eje num     enc
1: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge   9   1   UTF-8
2: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11  10 unkwown
3: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  12  11 unkwown
4: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  14 11A unkwown
```

but it is actually by chance since B is different from A (this should not be the case since A contains only `kom==101` and `gad=='A.C. Meyers Vænge'` observations):

```
   kom               gad eje num     enc
1: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge   9   1   UTF-8
2: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  10   1 unkwown
3: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11  10 unkwown
4: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  12  11 unkwown
5: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  13  11   UTF-8
6: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  14 11A unkwown
7: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  15 11A   UTF-8
8: 101 A.C. Meyers Vænge  16 11A   UTF-8
```

What is happening here?

EDIT: get `A`-like data

```
A <- data.table(
     kom = rep(101L,20),
     eje = 1L:20L,
     gad = rep("A.C. Meyers Vænge",20),
     num = rep(c('1','10','11','11A'),times=c(10,1,2,7)),
     enc = sample(c('unkwown','UTF-8'), 20, replace=TRUE)
)
Encoding(A$gad) <- A$enc
```

Comment: `Encoding(A$gade)` gives a mix of "UTF-8" and "unknown".

Comment: After investigation, the strange encoding comes from the function `str_replace()` (package `stringr`) applied to a character vector of `unkown` encoding. Actually, all fields containing exotic characters (as æ, ø or å... yes I am working in Denmark), are converted to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/c2c8387f51593765bfff3b78e0c757f63e2eab18), data.table now takes care of these mixed encodings implicitly by ensuring proper encodings while creating data.tables, as well as by ensuring proper encodings in functions like `unique()` and `duplicated()`.

See news item (23) under bugs for v1.9.7 in [README.md](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md).

Please test and write back if you face any further issues.

---

Now I get this:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7, commit 2096+
set.seed(2L)
A <- data.table(
     kom = rep(101L,20),
     eje = 1L:20L,
     gad = rep("A.C. Meyers Vænge",20),
     num = rep(c('1','10','11','11A'),times=c(10,1,2,7)),
     enc = sample(c('unkwown','UTF-8'), 20, replace=TRUE)
)
Encoding(A$gad) <- A$enc
setkey(A,kom,gad,num)
> unique(A)
#    kom eje               gad num     enc
# 1: 101   1 A.C. Meyers Vænge   1 unkwown
# 2: 101  11 A.C. Meyers Vænge  10   UTF-8
# 3: 101  12 A.C. Meyers Vænge  11 unkwown
# 4: 101  14 A.C. Meyers Vænge 11A unkwown
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted Arun, it is a mixed-encoding matter. Indeed, converting the column to a unique encoding with `enc2native()` makes `unique()` works properly:

```
A$gad2 <- enc2native(A$gad)
setkey(A,kom,gad2,num)
unique(A)
```

**BUT** I never *wanted* to get mixed encoding (and never specified such a thing in my code). Actually, even with native encoding on `gad2`,  `A[.(101,'A.C. Meyers Vænge')]` still gives a warning! The reason is simply:

```
Encoding(c('a','æ'))
[1] "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

As a consequence, `A[.(101,'A.C. Meyers Vænge')]` rises a warning (and a false answer), since a UTF-8 string, `A.C. Meyers Vænge`, is compared to a native-encoded column, `gad2`. One might force the characters to native encoding with `A[.(101,enc2native('A.C. Meyers Vænge'))]` but this seems pretty far-fetched to me.

I really do not get the point of this mixed encoding as a default!